# How to create Loading bar during post request using React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am working on reactjs project where i am fetching the data using post request. I am receiving the response , during this time i want to display loading bar ,i was able to display loadingbar using normal text it worked fine . I want a gif spinner to be replaced by the current "Loading.." text how can i achieve this ?

```html
let postData = { UserId: feedId }; 
    this.setState({ loading: "Loading..." }); // set laoding text to loading 
    
    if (feedId)
    {
      PostData('UserDetails', postData).then((result) => {
        
        let responseJson = result;
        this.setState({loading: ""}); // set loadingtext as empty
        
        this.setState({Userdata: responseJson.UserList});
        console.log(responseJson.UserList);
      });
     }
```

Comment: What exactly you don't know how to do? You don't know how to insert `<img` instead of text in React?

Comment: yes, if i insert image its not working .

Answer (score 2):

You could use a boolean value for the loading property of the state, and then conditionally render the spinner in your render method:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

  ...

  render() {
    return (
      this.state.loading 
        ? <Spinner />
        : <OtherComponent />
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of rendering the `loading` property from your state, you can add a conditional render in your JSX. E.g. only render your loading spinner when the loading property is `true`.

```
class Screen extends Component {
  postData() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    PostData().then((result) => {
      this.setState({ loading: false, UserData: result.UserList }); 
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.loading ? <img src="path/to/loading.gif" /> : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```